# How to fix visible jump in content after active sticky navigation using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I scroll, my sticky navigation works but there is a visible jump in the content. How do I fix this without using JQuery?

---

Here is the function:

```
window.onscroll = changePosition;

function changePosition() 
{
    var nav = document.getElementById("nav")

    if (window.pageYOffset > 230) {
        nav.style.position = "fixed";
        nav.style.top = "0";
        nav.style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementByID("content").style.marginTop = "250px";

    } else {
         nav.style.position = "";
            nav.style.top = "";
        }
}
```

Comment: Why is the margin 250px when the offset is 230px?

Comment: @LiYinKong Cuz my header is 230px. So when i scroll pass the header, the content would keep it's original position. At least that's what i want it to do